# Why finalize is required when GC can free all connections

Tags: java, io, garbage-collection, finalize

I have an object. It opened a `FileConnection`.
Now, I made the reference of object `null`.
Then `GC` [**G**arbage-**C**ollecter] runs.
So, `GC` will free the object and also close the `FileConnection` held by Object.

Then why I need to override finalize method?

Comment: You should never need to override `finalize`.  Just close the object before you assign its reference to `null`

Comment: [`Object::finalize`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) is deprecated.

Comment: You should rethink your habit of asking questions without [accepting answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to override the `finalize` method. Better yet forget about the `finalize` method altogether, it's deprecated.

But you do need to close the resource as soon as you're done with it. GC may keep unused objects around for a very long time. If you rely on GC closing system resources, you can run out of things like file handles, locks or sockets at OS level.
Those are limited resources.

Answer (score 2):

`finalize()` is called by GC exactly before it destroys the object. It could never happen at all and `finalize()` method will never be called.

If you take a resource (i.e. open a file), you have to correctly manually release it. You could use `AutoCloseable` interface.

Example:

```
try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("xxx"))) {
   // do smth.
} // scan.close() will be automatically called here
```

or more strictly:

```
Scanner scan = null;

try {
    scan = new Scanner(new File("xxx"));
} finally {
    if (scan != null)
        scan.close();  // instead of scan.finalize();
}
```

**P.S.** Never use `finalize()` method - this is outdated and used in very specific low-level solutions. If you ask this question, then it means that this is not your one.

Comment: What makes your second example “more strictly”? Your second example is how it was done before Java 7, with the huge disadvantage that an exception thrown by `close()` could hide a primary exception thrown in the `try` block.